# Making a row of equal-size scaling svgs that will allow me to adjust their size (based on width) and not break the design

Tags: html, css, svg, navbar, scaling

So I want a row of equal size svgs with some text underneath them (like a nav bar, but a bit larger). I almost have it working but there are some issues with what I have.  Just to be clear this is what I want:

1. I want the SVGs to be media responsive/to scale according to the width of container.
2. Everything needs to be horizontally centered.
3. I want the button container to be less than 100% (say 80 or 90) so that there are larger left and right margins (but still centered).
4. I want the svgs to remain the same size regardless of the size of the labeling text underneath (in my current version unequal text breaks the design which my snippet shows).
5. Because I'm not quite sure how I want the final look to be, I'd really like a robust design that will allow me to adjust the svgs to be larger or smaller and at the same time basically maintain the overall design/alignment. So, if I decide that in my final implementation I would like the svgs to say be slightly larger (perhaps 250% width, instead of 200%)I can retain the overall design by adjusting only this or only a few other parameters/margins.

I have a version that is almost right in this snippet, but there are some issues.  The biggest problem is the size of columns/svgs become different if the text of one child is longer than the others AND if you make the display small. If you change the text in the last item to match the others, everything looks good - but I want don't want text size to influence the size of the svgs.

In the desired implementation the svg size should depend on only two things: 1) the size of the containing div (i.e. maybe 80% of the page) and 2) the percentage of the containing div's width (e.g. if there are 3 items, its width/size should do something that takes into account 33% , if there are four items that number would be 25%, etc).  Here is the snippet where you can see that longer text for one item makes the scales of the svgs unequal.  I need the svgs to always scale equally.

If you can help, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

**Here is the snippet: when testing it please make sure your browser is small, otherwise you might not produce the unequal scaling.**

```css
.areaSVG {
  width: 200%;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0 33%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.ey-col-svg {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 34%;
}
.ey-nav-bar {
  padding-right: 4%;
  background-color: #333;
}
ul.ey-row-scale {
  max-height: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-left: 14%;
  /*padding left  + widht = 100*/
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ey-col-1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ey-text-content {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="ey-nav-bar">
  <ul class="ey-row-scale">

    <div class="ey-col-1">
      <a href="#">
        <li class="ey-col-svg">
          <svg width="100%" class="areaSVG" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 480 360" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <path id="circle-background" opacity="0.4196" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " d="
         M4.193,37.492c0-18.987,15.419-34.38,34.44-34.38c19.021,0,34.439,15.393,34.439,34.38c0,18.987-15.418,34.381-34.439,34.381
         C19.613,71.873,4.193,56.48,4.193,37.492L4.193,37.492z" />
            <path id="sclera" class="fillWhite" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="
         M11.41,38.895c27.619-31.029,41.313-9.542,49.646-2.012c-4.306,6.07-12.69,27.49-46.392,9.919c0,0-5.375-3.548-5.641-4.75
         C12.787,37.379,11.41,38.895,11.41,38.895z" />
            <ellipse id="iris" class="fillDark" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" cx="38.196" cy="36.63" rx="16.202" ry="15.686" />
            <ellipse id="pupil" class="fillWhite" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" cx="38.529" cy="36.954" rx="5.628" ry="5.449" />
            <path id="eyelid" class="fillDark" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="
         M56.955,26.227c5.438,2.787,12.803,9.595,12.803,9.595s-2.338,3.235-5.677,2.588c-4.027,3.396-13.345,29.705-49.417,8.393
         c33.702,17.571,42.086-3.849,46.392-9.919c-8.333-7.53-22.026-29.018-49.646,2.012c0,0-2.94,1.806-4.112-1.456
         c-1.172-3.261,2.481-0.477,4.009-2.911c1.527-2.434,3.674-3.557,7.682-6.792c-4.008,0.646-7.348,3.558-7.348,3.558
         c10.521-10.835,31.379-17.498,53.107-4.205C64.748,27.089,59.404,26.119,56.955,26.227z" />
          </svg>
        </li>
        <li class="ey-text-content">item 1</li>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="ey-col-1">
      <a href="#">
        <li class="ey-col-svg">
          <svg width="100%" class="areaSVG" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 480 360" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <path id="circle-background" opacity="0.4196" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " d="
         M4.193,37.492c0-18.987,15.419-34.38,34.44-34.38c19.021,0,34.439,15.393,34.439,34.38c0,18.987-15.418,34.381-34.439,34.381
         C19.613,71.873,4.193,56.48,4.193,37.492L4.193,37.492z" />
            <path id="sclera" class="fillWhite" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="
         M11.41,38.895c27.619-31.029,41.313-9.542,49.646-2.012c-4.306,6.07-12.69,27.49-46.392,9.919c0,0-5.375-3.548-5.641-4.75
         C12.787,37.379,11.41,38.895,11.41,38.895z" />
            <ellipse id="iris" class="fillDark" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" cx="38.196" cy="36.63" rx="16.202" ry="15.686" />
            <ellipse id="pupil" class="fillWhite" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" cx="38.529" cy="36.954" rx="5.628" ry="5.449" />
            <path id="eyelid" class="fillDark" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="
         M56.955,26.227c5.438,2.787,12.803,9.595,12.803,9.595s-2.338,3.235-5.677,2.588c-4.027,3.396-13.345,29.705-49.417,8.393
         c33.702,17.571,42.086-3.849,46.392-9.919c-8.333-7.53-22.026-29.018-49.646,2.012c0,0-2.94,1.806-4.112-1.456
         c-1.172-3.261,2.481-0.477,4.009-2.911c1.527-2.434,3.674-3.557,7.682-6.792c-4.008,0.646-7.348,3.558-7.348,3.558
         c10.521-10.835,31.379-17.498,53.107-4.205C64.748,27.089,59.404,26.119,56.955,26.227z" />
          </svg>

        </li>
        <li class="ey-text-content">Item 2</li>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="ey-col-1">
      <a href="#">
        <li class="ey-col-svg">
          <svg width="100%" class="areaSVG" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 480 360" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <path id="circle-background" opacity="0.4196" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " d="
         M4.193,37.492c0-18.987,15.419-34.38,34.44-34.38c19.021,0,34.439,15.393,34.439,34.38c0,18.987-15.418,34.381-34.439,34.381
         C19.613,71.873,4.193,56.48,4.193,37.492L4.193,37.492z" />
            <path id="sclera" class="fillWhite" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="
         M11.41,38.895c27.619-31.029,41.313-9.542,49.646-2.012c-4.306,6.07-12.69,27.49-46.392,9.919c0,0-5.375-3.548-5.641-4.75
         C12.787,37.379,11.41,38.895,11.41,38.895z" />
            <ellipse id="iris" class="fillDark" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" cx="38.196" cy="36.63" rx="16.202" ry="15.686" />
            <ellipse id="pupil" class="fillWhite" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" cx="38.529" cy="36.954" rx="5.628" ry="5.449" />
            <path id="eyelid" class="fillDark" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="
         M56.955,26.227c5.438,2.787,12.803,9.595,12.803,9.595s-2.338,3.235-5.677,2.588c-4.027,3.396-13.345,29.705-49.417,8.393
         c33.702,17.571,42.086-3.849,46.392-9.919c-8.333-7.53-22.026-29.018-49.646,2.012c0,0-2.94,1.806-4.112-1.456
         c-1.172-3.261,2.481-0.477,4.009-2.911c1.527-2.434,3.674-3.557,7.682-6.792c-4.008,0.646-7.348,3.558-7.348,3.558
         c10.521-10.835,31.379-17.498,53.107-4.205C64.748,27.089,59.404,26.119,56.955,26.227z" />
          </svg>
        </li>
        <li class="ey-text-content">item 3</li>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ey-col-1">
      <a href="#">
        <li class="ey-col-svg">
          <svg width="100%" class="areaSVG" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 480 360" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <path id="circle-background" opacity="0.4196" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " d="
         M4.193,37.492c0-18.987,15.419-34.38,34.44-34.38c19.021,0,34.439,15.393,34.439,34.38c0,18.987-15.418,34.381-34.439,34.381
         C19.613,71.873,4.193,56.48,4.193,37.492L4.193,37.492z" />
            <path id="sclera" class="fillWhite" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="
         M11.41,38.895c27.619-31.029,41.313-9.542,49.646-2.012c-4.306,6.07-12.69,27.49-46.392,9.919c0,0-5.375-3.548-5.641-4.75
         C12.787,37.379,11.41,38.895,11.41,38.895z" />
            <ellipse id="iris" class="fillDark" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" cx="38.196" cy="36.63" rx="16.202" ry="15.686" />
            <ellipse id="pupil" class="fillWhite" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" cx="38.529" cy="36.954" rx="5.628" ry="5.449" />
            <path id="eyelid" class="fillDark" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="
         M56.955,26.227c5.438,2.787,12.803,9.595,12.803,9.595s-2.338,3.235-5.677,2.588c-4.027,3.396-13.345,29.705-49.417,8.393
         c33.702,17.571,42.086-3.849,46.392-9.919c-8.333-7.53-22.026-29.018-49.646,2.012c0,0-2.94,1.806-4.112-1.456
         c-1.172-3.261,2.481-0.477,4.009-2.911c1.527-2.434,3.674-3.557,7.682-6.792c-4.008,0.646-7.348,3.558-7.348,3.558
         c10.521-10.835,31.379-17.498,53.107-4.205C64.748,27.089,59.404,26.119,56.955,26.227z" />
          </svg>
        </li>
        <li class="ey-text-content">LONGERTEXT</li>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So in this case, I have added a `white-space: nowrap;` in your CSS that is keeping the text on one line You can leave that if you like or take it out.

My first suggestion is to take `white-space: nowrap;`out (if you want to) and `font-size`:

```
.ey-text-content {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 95%; /*Add This. Adjust to your liking*/
  **white-space: nowrap;** /*Take Out*/
}
```

I forgot to include a Width in the `.eye-col-1` which is causing it to go out of its guidelines.
So in `.ey-col-1` You need to add this `width: 20%;` Doing this should resolve all your text related issues. You can see the Example [here](http://codepen.io/RTarson/pen/WwMNjX)

Comment: please show it with my snippett's code. The svg size issue remains unanswered.

Comment: also - while i appreciate your help - in the code pen you show, when I minimize the window, the svgs become different sizes, which is highly undesirable.